# Shared transition animation of TextView with different color from one activity to another

Tags: android, animation, textview, transition

I am using shared transition animation with TextView. I have two activities from where I transits TextView from first activity to second.In first activity text color of TextView is Black and background of whole layout is white.While in second activity text color of TextView is white and background of TextView is black, the whole layout of activity is black on top and white on middle.When transition animation starts First activity's TextView color becomes white so it does not appear through out the animation as background of first activity is white.It only appears when it enters in second activity.So transition does not seem good enough. Is there any idea how to remain text color of First activity's TextView to black and after that make it white?
Or can we make shades in TextView's color from white to gray and then black?
Please let me know if it is posible or not? OR Is there any solution to this?